# Strict Standards: Non-static method dbInstance::getInstance()

Tags: php

I can't figure out why this error in php 5.4.

**Strict Standards: Non-static method dbInstance::getInstance() should not be called statically**

The class is:

```
class dbInstance
{
    private static $db;

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (! self::$db) self::$db = new db();
        return self::$db;
    }
}
```

I call it like:

```
 $registry->db = $db = dbInstance::getInstance()
```

Thanks

Comment: Where are you actually calling the method though?

Comment: Just for the records, [singletons are evil](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/40373/so-singletons-are-bad-then-what)

Comment: @TimCooper - $registry->db = $db = dbInstance::getInstance()

Comment: Just as the error message states, you're calling a non-static method statically.  So, that's obviously not the code that produced the error.  Either you haven't pasted the real code, or you're looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the error. Are you absolutely sure you've edited the right file? Or maybe you are seeing a cached version of the output?

```
<?php
$db = dbInstance::getInstance();

class dbInstance
{
    private static $db;

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (! self::$db) self::$db = new db();
        return self::$db;
    }
}

class db {
    public function __construct() {
        echo 'db::construct filemtime=', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', filemtime(__FILE__)), ' PHPVERSION=', PHP_VERSION;
    }
}
```

prints on my computer

```
db::construct filemtime=2012-07-27 14:50:37 PHPVERSION=5.4.1
```